# SQLite no such column even though everything spelled right and there is correct spacing

Tags: android, sqlite

I am learning `android` programming and `sqlite` at the same time. I am creating a table like:

```
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE " + BOOK_TABLE + " ("
        + BookContract._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        + BookContract.TITLE + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
        + BookContract.AUTHORS + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
        + BookContract.ISBN + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
        + BookContract.PRICE + " TEXT NOT NULL );";
```

In my function that fetches all books in the database, my query is:

```
String query =  "SELECT " +
            BOOK_TABLE + "." + BookContract._ID + ", " +
            BookContract.TITLE + ", " +
            BookContract.PRICE + ", " +
            BookContract.ISBN + ", " +
            "GROUP_CONCAT(" + AuthorContract.NAME + ", ',') as " + BookContract.AUTHORS +
            " FROM " + BOOK_TABLE + " LEFT OUTER JOIN " + AUTHOR_TABLE + " ON " +
            BOOK_TABLE + "." + BookContract._ID + "=" +
            AUTHOR_TABLE + "." + AuthorContract.BOOK_FOREIGN_KEY +
            " GROUP BY " + BOOK_TABLE + "." + BookContract._ID + ", " +
            BookContract.TITLE + ", " + BookContract.PRICE + ", " + BookContract.ISBN;
```

Here is how the string actually looks like for the table creation:

```
CREATE TABLE bookTable (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, title TEXT NOT NULL, authors TEXT NOT NULL, isbn TEXT NOT NULL, price TEXT NOT NULL );
```

and for the query:

```
 SELECT bookTable._id, title, price, isbn, GROUP_CONCAT(name, ',') as authors FROM bookTable LEFT OUTER JOIN authorTable ON bookTable._id = authorTable.book_fk GROUP BY bookTable._id, title, price, isbn
```

I swear I am going insane on this because similar `stackOverflow` posts asking the similar problem have minor spelling mistakes or missing spaces, however mine seems to work correctly on an online `sql simulator`!

When i do a `database.rawQuery(query, null)`, the error saying that *`there is no such column: price appears in the log`*.

EDIT:

There is another Author table that has the missing name column that was mentioned in the comments, here it is for clarity:

```
 String AUTHOR_TABLE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE " + AUTHOR_TABLE + " ("
        + AuthorContract._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        + AuthorContract.BOOK_FOREIGN_KEY + " INTEGER NOT NULL, "
        + AuthorContract.NAME  + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
        + "FOREIGN KEY ("+ AuthorContract.BOOK_FOREIGN_KEY+") " +
        "REFERENCES "+BOOK_TABLE+"("+BookContract._ID+") ON DELETE CASCADE);";
```

which gives the string:

```
CREATE TABLE authorTable (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, book_fk INTEGER NOT NULL, name TEXT NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY (book_fk) REFERENCES bookTable(_id) ON DELETE CASCADE);
```

Comment: Are you creating the database first than execute the above query.. I have also stuck in the same problem earlier that... i have not create the database and fire the query...plz check it first that....you are creating the database first and than executing the query

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT(name, ',')`? There is no name column

Comment: @cricket_007 seems is from table `authorTable`

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha I open the database first and then call the fetchAllBooks() function so I think it is creating the database first and then executing. What I find weird is that why is only price not being recognized and the others are.

Comment: @user3261941 did you try removing price column  from select and see what happen?

Comment: @g2o it gives the same error for isbn now

Comment: try adding bookTable.isbn, bookTable.price to each corresponding element on the query...

Comment: @g2o gvies same error but says no such column: bookTable.price now

Comment: Try this  : SELECT bt._id, bt.title, bt.price, bt.isbn, GROUP_CONCAT(at.name, ',') as authors
 FROM bookTable bt
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
authorTable at
ON bt._id = at.book_fk 
GROUP BY bt._id, bt.title, bt.price, bt.isbn

Comment: @RakeshSoni that was the query I had after doing g2o's reccommendation. It gave the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just **uninstall** your app from mobile and then re-run.
i hope it works if there is no problem in code.

Comment: THIS WAS IT!! This fixed the solution. Many thanks to the others who helped too.